# Oracle Sql: How can I output a table from procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table A(a1,a2,a3);

I want to write a procedure like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE B
AS
BEGIN
.........
..........
SELECT * FROM A;
END
```

so that when I do `EXECUTE B;`

It should output table A

as happens in `select * from A;`

See I tried with the other answers but it was not working for me that is why i posted this question

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Output to where? Who/what will call the procedure? Why not query the table directly? What did you try from other answers and what happened?

Comment: See I tried the queries but it is giving me compilation errors as if it is not allowing the select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server (which I believe you indicated you were coming from in a different question) is different than Oracle.  You can't just have a procedure that executes a query.

You could define your procedure to have an `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE b( p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc 
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM a;
END;
```

The caller of your procedure would then need to know how to fetch from that ref cursor and do something meaningful with the results.  If you are using SQL*Plus

```
SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec b( :rc );
SQL> print rc
```

If you are using something other than SQL*Plus, the code would likely be different.

Alternately, your procedure could return a PL/SQL collection.  Or it could be a pipelined table function rather than a procedure in which case you could use it in the `FROM` clause of a query.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for posts to see a way to output the data from oracle function for my ssis package, so thought i will share the info on working with pipeline in oracle to output like table

--create table type object to define format of the rows

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE

  IS OBJECT (

  COL1 VARCHAR(100),

  COL2 NUMBER 

                           );
```

--create table type based on above object

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OUTPUT_TABLE

  AS TABLE OF OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE


  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_OUT_TABLE (INPARAM1 IN NUMBER)

        RETURN OUTPUT_TABLE PIPELINED

        IS             

        BEGIN

                FOR RECORD_OUTPUT IN ( 

                        SELECT * FROM (

                              SELECT CAST('OUTPUT SAM1' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS COL1,CAST( 1 AS NUMBER) AS COL2 FROM DUAL

                              UNION ALL

                              SELECT CAST('OUTPUT SAM2' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS COL1,CAST( 2 AS NUMBER) AS COL2  FROM DUAL

                              ) SAM_TEMP -- replace this sub query with your query

                              WHERE COL2=INPARAM1

                              )

                LOOP

                      PIPE ROW (OUTPUT_TABLE_TYPE(RECORD_OUTPUT.COL1,RECORD_OUTPUT.COL2));

                END LOOP;                    

        END;
```

To get the output we need to run below select statement

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(FN_OUT_TABLE(2));
```

find more info @ http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2013/12/output-table-or-multiple-rows-from-stored-procedure-function.html

Comment: This is function, not stored procedure. For example, you could not work with transactions inside function