# Working with Oracle TABLE TYPE return values in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am a beginner in SSIS and have a requirement of fetch data from Oracle database.

Oracle Dev Team has deployed a package to return data as TABLE TYPE in Oracle. We require the package since data manipulation needs to be based on parameters provided by user.

After reading the values, I need to insert data to tables in MSSQL.

When I try to read via SSIS I am getting an error as, ***Invalid parameter binding - Parameter name: CustomTableTypeFromOracle***. The CustomTableTypeFromOracle is a return type, not an OUT parameter.

Is there a way to read TABLE TYPE return values in SSIS?

Tried google but couldn't find a solution specifically relating to TABLE TYPE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of component did you use and what does your code look like? Here are some links that might help but you need to supply more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902765/oracle-sql-how-can-i-output-a-table-from-procedure.. looks like you also asked the question here and did not respond to any answers, so I guess you will not respond to any answers here either: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ee7b609-6e56-4dc7-89a6-4a0d21d6e716/reading-table-type-return-values-from-oracle-pl-sql-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for helping me out on this. We were able to sort the issue out with ODBC connection as mentioned in the [query](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8ee7b609-6e56-4dc7-89a6-4a0d21d6e716/reading-table-type-return-values-from-oracle-pl-sql-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices) I have asked in SSIS forum. Again thanks for your time and effort. Much appreciated.